# My android app takes 50MB memory on Android 5.0

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I was developing my android app on Android 4.1.1,  I am using listview to display 100 images, I am using `Universal Image Loader` to display all images.

My app uses about 20MB on Android 4.1.1, when loads more images it goes up to 30MB which is acceptable. Unfortunately, when I test my app on Android 5.0, it uses about 40MB memory and when it loads more images it goes to 55MB and makes my app quite slow.

Here is how I define Universal Image Loader options:

```
    private DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .delayBeforeLoading(100)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .postProcessor(null)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.empty_loading)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.empty_loading)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) //makes image smaller
//            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300, true, true, true)) //comment out this line, then flickering is gone
            .build();
```

I have no idea why it happens, please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at your cache folder size

Comment: can you explain how to check it and how to modify the cache size please?

Comment: What is that device running on Android 5?

Comment: Im using Genymotion emulator Nexus 5 Api 21

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is not answer of this question. I code it based on your comment. How to get application cache size :

```
File cacheDirectory = mContext.getCacheDir();
long size = 0;
File[] files = cacheDirectory.listFiles();
for (File f:files) {
    size = size+f.length();
}
```

Look if its different size in jellybean vs lolipop

Answer (score 0):

The issue is obvious loading 100 images will cause memory issue if not done properly.

It gets worse with high resolution images, it would be best for you to use a library that can manage this task for you or even caching and try to reduce the resolution.

Comment: Im using Universal Image Loader, everything works fine on Android 4.1.1, it is not working properly on Android 5.0.

Comment: @haifzhan good so try to reduce the resolution and give it another try